# mathematics / bad logic in jquery animation / for each loop to give a falling effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, foreach

so i have this piece of code that i'm trying to make up the logic of...
what i want to do is sequence-wise animate a falling brick...
however, as the index increases in array, the duration increases, clearly a fault in my logic.. i could hard code for the 5 step of the table column but thats way ugly... following is the code..

```
spot.each(function (index, val) {
//$(this).css({ backgroundColor: "blue" })
$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, {
  duration: (index + 0.5) * 400
}).animate({
  backgroundColor: "blue"
}, {
  duration: (index + 0.5) * 400
}).animate({
  backgroundColor: "white"
}, {
  duration: (index + 0.4) * 400,
  complete: function () {
    counter = counter + 1;
    if (counter == 5) {
      counter = 0;
      animateTable(spot)
    }
  }
})
```

[image]

so spot is an array of "tds" (table cells) ..
while, i'd be very happy to find a solution for this, i would be okay if i could some how add a syncronous delay and use $(this).css instead to just perceive as shifting the blue box from top to bottom..(it would be css bg -> white to css bg-> blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i altered the above code by altering it to this and minimizing the random factor multiplying to index to some extent, not fully though. still not sure how i'd approach this but the following did help.

```
function animateTable(spot) {
  var rand = getRandomFloat(0.4, 0.9)
  var randomColor = theColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * theColors.length)];
  var counter = 0

  spot.each(function (index, val) {
    if (!gRunning) {
      $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, {
        duration: (index + 1) * rand * 3000,
        easing: "linear",
        step: function () {
          if (countDownRunning) {
            $(this).stop()
            //console.log("stopped")
          }
        }
      }, $(this).attr("data-animating", true)).animate({
        backgroundColor: randomColor
      }, {
        duration: (index + 1) * 200,
        easing: "linear",
        step: function () {
          if (countDownRunning) {
            $(this).stop()
            //console.log("stopped")
          }
        }
      }).animate({
        backgroundColor: "white"
      }, {
        duration: (index + 1) * 200,
        easing: "linear",
        step: function () {
          if (countDownRunning) {
            $(this).stop()
            //console.log("stopped")
          }
        },
        complete: function () {

          counter = counter + 1;
          if (counter == 5) {
            counter = 0;
            initAnim()
            $(this).attr("data-animating", false)
          }
        }
      })
    } else {
      return false
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming index increases. If you don't want duration to increase, index should not be included in the duration math at all. For example:

```
duration: (index + 0.5) * 400
```

becomes:

```
duration: 0.5 * 400
```

Comment: i want steady increment against indexes, so it has to be a part of the formula.
otherwise i can't really make the animation as shown about.

0.5 * 400 animates all of the blue boxes in animation at once rather than in steps as above.